# Zabbix-agent shows in netstat even when not installed

Tags: networking, uninstall, software-uninstall

I am looking trough my ESTABLISHED netstat connections and what seems not right is zabbix-agent running without being installed. One of my lines on *$ sudo netstat | grep ESTABLISHED* is the following:

```
tcp        0      0 rozkvet.local:41201     trelay.3so:zabbix-agent ESTABLISHED
```

Zabbix-agent is not installed, is there some residue service I need to get rid of?

```
~$ sudo apt-get autoremove zabbix-agent
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'zabbix-agent' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `zabbix-agent` is shown as the remote part of the connection it doesn't have to be installed on your system.

If you run `netstat` without the `-n` option it tries to resolve port numbers using `/etc/services`.  So `zabbix-agent` just stands for port 10050, and there may `zabbix-agent`  running, or any other program that can be configured to use that port.

You can use

```
sudo fuser -v 41201/tcp
```

to find the program that is using port 41201 on your local system.